# Migrate client-server from UDP to TCP

Tags: java, sockets, server, tcp, udp

Server

```
public class ServidorSimetrico {

    static int PUERTO = 5000;
    static byte[] claveSimetrica = {0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79};
    static String mensajeDesencriptado;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {

        System.out.println("- Mensaje desencriptado " + Desencriptar());

    }

    public static String Desencriptar() throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        //ClaveSecreta
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(claveSimetrica, "AES");
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO);
        DatagramPacket packet;
        byte[] data;
        System.out.println("Escuchando...");

        data = new byte[1024];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
        String message = new String(packet.getData());
        System.out.println("- Mensaje encriptado: " + message);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        // Reiniciar Cipher al modo desencriptado
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] plainBytesDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
        mensajeDesencriptado = new String(plainBytesDecrypted);

        return mensajeDesencriptado;
    }

}
```

Client

```
public class ClienteSimetrico {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

        Encriptar("HOLA");

    }

    public static String Encriptar(String mensajeEncriptado) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] ipAddr = new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1};
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        byte[] plainBytes = mensajeEncriptado.getBytes();
        //ClaveSecreta
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(ServidorSimetrico.claveSimetrica, "AES");
        // Crear objeto Cipher e inicializar modo encriptación
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");// Transformación
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] EncryptedData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(EncryptedData, EncryptedData.length, address, ServidorSimetrico.PUERTO);// Bytes
        System.out.println("- Mensaje desencriptado: " + new String(plainBytes));
        System.out.println("- Mensaje encriptado: " + new String(EncryptedData));
        System.out.println("Enviando mensaje al Servidor: " + plainBytes);
        socket.send(packet);
        System.out.println("Mensaje enviado");
        socket.close();

    return mensajeEncriptado;
    }

}
```

How can I get the exact same functionality of this simple server-cliente app but using TPC (ServerSocket and Socket) instead of UDP (DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket)?
I've tried everthing but at the step of getting the data from the packet I dont know how to do that part with TCP sockets.

Comment: It sounds as though you have your new application working, except for one thing. Please post your almost working code and explain exactly what you are having trouble with. See [ask]. Sockets work with streams of bytes rather than packets, at the application level.

Comment: That is my almost working code. @tgdavies